# 1 server, different database to use per subdomain

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

Im using the following code to run a nodejs-app (small loginsystem with Passport) on port 3010.
The variable 'course' is used to load a config-file with credentials for MySQL (yes, will be changed to other database later).

But, i have 2 subdomains that needs to redirect to the same nodejs-app, but with different mysql-credentials. Whats the best solution? I tried reading out the subdomain and get the configuration that belongs to this subdomain, but once its set in the app, its being used for all subdomains.

The amount of subdomains could, in theory get to 50.

````
var course='subdomain';

// set up ======================================================================
var express  = require('express');
var session  = require('express-session');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app      = express();
var port     = 3010;

var passport = require('passport');
var flash    = require('connect-flash');

// configuration ===============================================================
require('./config/passport')(passport,course); // pass passport for configuration

// set up our express application
app.use(cookieParser()); // read cookies (needed for auth)
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.set('view engine', 'ejs'); // set up ejs for templating

// required for passport
app.use(session({
    secret: 'fds4Fgsd#SDSdsdss#$FDS#',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
 } ));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session()); // persistent login sessions
app.use(flash()); // use connect-flash for flash messages stored in session

var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

// routes ======================================================================
require('./app/routes.js')(app, passport,course); // load our routes and pass in our app and fully configured passport

// launch ======================================================================
server.listen(port);
console.log('The magic happens on port ' + port);```
````

Comment: you can try this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35344588/node-js-multiple-subdomains

Comment: Ok, i added this in server.js
I cant use that var "conn" in a module (module.exports)? How to make that global?

Comment: // use connection from res.locals at further routes

Comment: Thanks, but how to use in a module?

`module.exports = function(passport) {
    
    // used to serialize the user for the session
    passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
        done(null, user.id);
    });
    
    // used to deserialize the user
    passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
        res.local.connection.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ? ", [id], function (err, rows) {
            done(err, rows[0]);
        });
    });

};`